# Locate text in webpage and click - Eclipse Selenium

Tags: html, eclipse, selenium, web, button

I want to locate some text in a webpage. This text is inside a list, and for each value of this list I need to locate the text in webpage and click in a button that belong to this value. This is my code:

```
List<String> lstFaturasAProcessar = new ArrayList<>();
for (String fatNumber : lstFaturasAProcessar) {
             if(driver.getPageSource().contains(fatNumber))
             driver.findElement(By.className("btn-default btn-small dropdown-trigger")).click();
}
```

Basically I am saying, if the value of that list is present in webpage, click button. All the values of list have different buttons, and all the buttons have the same class name, but when It click button nothing happens. Buttons' HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-default btn-small dropdown-trigger">
                <span>Obter documentos<i class="icon2-arrow-down"></i></span>
              </button>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What are the contents of `List<String> lstFaturasAProcessar`? When you already have an `ArrayList<>` why do you need `driver.getPageSource()` again?

Comment: But even if I don't use driver.getPageSource() it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

1. it could be possible that there are more than one parent with matching class name, it picks the first element which may not be the button .hence use a css or xpath to locate the button elements with matching text rather than page source.
2. For some angular/react applications try with clicking on span
   Ex :- //button/span and click
3. You may try this, get the parent of this button with some unique identifier like I’d/name etc and then try to do a css selector to the matching button you want to click,
   Example : xpath :- //div[@id= ‘blahblah’] / button

Comment: But none of this buttons have unique identifier. This webpage have different values and next to this values there is a specific button ("download" button)

Comment: It's like:
value 1                DOWNLOAD
value 2                DOWNLOAD
value 3                DOWNLOAD
...

And I just want to download from the values that exist in my list